# Странное поведение инфиксного метода

Tags: android, kotlin, logcat

В методе `onCreate` у `Activity` у меня есть код:

```
val map = mapOf(1 to "one", 2 to "two", 3 to "three")
Log.e(TAG, "$map")
```

и отдельно в этой же `Activity` у меня есть инфиксный метод `to`:

```
infix fun Any.to(other: Any) : Pair<Any, Any> {
        Log.e(TAG, "internal to $other")
        return Pair(this, other)
 }
```

если всё так, то всё работает логично, в логах видно, что этот метод to вызывается 3 раза:

> internal to one
>
> internal to two
>
> internal to three
>
> {1=one, 2=two, 3=three}

а если убрать только `$other` из строчки с логированием:

```
infix fun Any.to(other: Any) : Pair<Any, Any> {
        Log.e(TAG, "internal to")
        return Pair(this, other)
}
```

то этот метод почему-то вызывается 2 раза... По крайней мере, в Logcat в этом случае вывод такой:

> internal to
>
> internal to
>
> {1=one, 2=two, 3=three}

Почему так происходит? Вроде как изменяю я только строчку с логированием...

**P.S.** Я пробовала включать дебаг, ставить точку останова на строчку с логированием - и в этом случае метод `to` выполняется три раза, и вывод в Logcat такой же, как в первом примере (с `$other`)...

**UPD**

И то же самое странное поведение проявляется при выполнении следующего кода:

```
Log.d(TAG, "${
            listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9)
                    .map {
                        Log.d(TAG, "map")
                        it * it
                    }
                    .find { it > 6 }
}")
```

При выполнении этого фрагмента кода в Logcat выводится:

> map
>
> map
>
> 9

при том, что код

```
Log.d(TAG, "${
            listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9)
                    .map {
                        Log.d(TAG, "map $it")
                        it * it
                    }
                    .find { it > 6 }
}")
```

выводит

> map 1
>
> map 2
>
> map 3
>
> map 4
>
> map 8
>
> map 9
>
> 9

Comment: Версия Котлина? Проверил на JVM версии 1.2.71 - все работает как надо.

Comment: Та же. Версия Android Studio - 3.2.

Comment: Хотя сейчас попробовала в AS 3.0.2 - та же ситуация. И, кстати, я пробовала ещё выводить на UI, а не в Logcat - там всё нормально. Т.е., кажется, проблема в Logcat...